Is AWS Cognito Custom UI customization broken?
The AWS Cognito Edit Custom UI interface seems to be broken. I can upload a custom image, or a custom CSS file but not both? And if one is already uploaded, I cannot upload the other? Is there a work-around for this or is it just a bug in the AWS console? Here is the error I get if I try any of the following:

Upload image and css file at the same time
Upload image if CSS file already exists
Upload CSS file if image already exists


I am hoping that someone has found a work-around?

I gave up waiting for AWS to fix this oddity so the work-around is to just do the image load in your custom-css file. The top of my custom-css.css now looks like this:
.logo-customizable {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.banner-customizable {
  padding: 0px;
  background-image: url("https://[your url]/logo.png");
  background-color: #25327B;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
}

Which allows a full-box logo image at the top of the login panel.
